# Substitute factor by ratio in maxima expression

Tags: maxima

I have this expression in maxima:

```
a^2/sqrt((a*cos(φ))^2+(b*sin(φ))^2)
```

Can I have maxima rewrite it in terms of a factor times a/b?

Answer (score 0):

```
v:a^2/sqrt((a*cos(φ))^2+(b*sin(φ))^2);

sqrt(trigsimp(ratsubst(k,a/b,v)^2));
```

[image]